# Binomial-CDF/binomial-test for classifier significance testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

### General Problem Description and Goal

I set up a matching algorithm that matches a user input (string) with a list of possible values (words) that is conclusive but very large (some 5 digit possibilities) and I **want to evaluate the quality in terms of accuracy of the algorithm and give a significance** but not compare it to any other algorithm. The problem came up since it is not possible to restrict the user input, as it is pulled from a website not operated by myself and the user input is partly incorrect e.g. due to typos but I know all possible meaningful inputs. The possible inputs are not perfectly uniformly distributed as some words appear more often than others, nevertheless, there is no predominant class.

### Approach

Inspired by [this site](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ebhiksha/courses/10-601/hypothesistesting/hyptesting_onesample_Bernoulli.html) I thought of simply using the binomial CDF, as I think, that the results of my matching algorithm are bernoulli distributed: X_i = 1 if correct and X_i = 0 if false. Therefore I draw a randomized sample of 1000 results and manually inspected if they are correct. That resulted in 15 false matchings and 985 correct matchings. Then I calculated the CDF for k = 985, n = 1000 and p = 0,95, implying that my algorithm is 95% correct. That gave me a value of 0.99999999905952 which would allow me to discard H_0 that my algorithm is worse than 95% correct matchings at the 1% significance level.

### Problem and Question

Is that a common and acceptable approach? If not, what kind of test should i consider?

Are there any publications which are a good source for that approach, as I only found the above linked website?

Comment: Of possible interest: Benavoli, Alessio, et al. "Time for a change: a tutorial for comparing multiple classifiers through Bayesian analysis." The Journal of Machine Learning Research 18.1 (2017): 2653-2688. https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume18/16-305/16-305.pdf

Comment: But do note the issues with accuracy as a performance metric:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he
https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/
https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359936/247274 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/proper-scoring-rule-when-there-is-a-decision-to-make-e-g-spam-vs-ham-email
https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en